# What is the official website of the Vietnam embassy in Canada?

Tags: online-resources, vietnam, embassies, scams

I am looking for the official website of the embassy of Vietnam in Canada. After looking it up on Google, I found a first website that looks serious:

http://vietem-ca.com/

However, I also found another ["worldwide" website](http://www.vietnameseembassy.org/canada+ottawa.html) listing among others the Canadian embassy and it points to

http://www.vietnamembassy-canada.ca/index.php

which can not be found. I have found on the first website [a page warning of other suspicious websites that are not official](http://vietem-ca.com/press-releases/warning-about-private-websites) (but pretending you are official and others are not is not necessarily a good sign). Also the website mentions multiple email addresses to contact the embassy, from private providers (vietem-inter@uniserve.com or vietnamembassy@rogers.com). And to finish, the websites of the embassies of Vietnam in different countries (returned by Google) do not seem to follow a pattern : there are `www.vietnamembassy.org.uk`, `vietnamembassy-usa.org`, `vietnamembassy.org.au`, `www.vnembassy.net`.

So, is the website I found (http://vietem-ca.com/) the right website? And in general, are there ways to make sure we browse the embassy's official website, for any country?

Comment: Hmm. The canadian government retains a list of addresses and phone numbers for embassies - but rarely includes an offical website link. http://www.international.gc.ca/protocol-protocole/reps.aspx?lang=eng

Comment: @Cmaster And the travel advice page - http://travel.gc.ca/destinations/vietnam - also points to the same place. Grrr.

Comment: Maybe just call the number on international.gc.ca link that CMaster provided and see what they say. The (613) 236-0772 number.

Comment: Are you sure you *need* the embassy?  It is possible to get a visa-preapproval letter [without dealing with the Vietnamese government directly](https://blueapsara.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/vietnamese-pre-approved-visa-process/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offical website for the Vietnamese embassy in Canada is:
http://www.vietem-ca.com/

This is from a list of Vietnamese diplomatic missions abroad provided by the [Vietnamese government here](http://visa.mofa.gov.vn/Contact.aspx) (Although my experience of Vietnam and the Internet would not give me complete faith in it being kept up to date). The website with the lists was linked to as an offical Vietnamese government page [via the Australian SmartTraveller page](https://smartraveller.gov.au/countries/vietnam). It's also linked to from the [website of the Vietnamese embassy in the](http://vietnamembassy.org.uk/index.php?action=p&ct=Consular%20Services%20for%20UK%20residents#VISA) UK.

Answer (score 2):

The whois of vietem-ca: http://whois.domaintools.com/vietem-ca.com

The whois of vietnamembassy-canada.ca: http://whois.domaintools.com/vietnamembassy-canada.ca

They both say Wilbroad as the street, have the same postal code and are both in Ottawa.

One possibility: the embassy website was hosted by one of their tech guys and then when he left and another was onboard they just got another domain for it. At which point both would kinda be valid, but at differing points in time.

Comment: Note that the vietnamembassy-canada.ca domain expired and is in its grace period.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [link](http://vietem-ca.com/) of the Vietnamite Embassy in Canada

Comment: How do you know?